# Form array of property names found in a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following object

```
var columns = {ContributionType: "Employer Contribution",
               Employee1: "0",
               Employee2: "0",
               Employee3: "0"
              };
```

From this I need to form an array with they property keys alone like following

```
var keys=["ContributionType", "Employee1", "Employee2", "Employee3"];
```

**The number of properties is dynamic**

Question:
**How can I achieve this using lodash or pure JavaScript?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var columns = {ContributionType: "Employer Contribution",
               Employee1: "0",
               Employee2: "0",
               Employee3: "0"
              };
var keys = Object.keys(columns);
console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr=[];
for (var key in columns)
{
//by using hasOwnProperty(key) we make sure that keys of
//the prototype are not included if any
if(columns.hasOwnProperty(key))
{
    arr.push(key);
}
}
```

Comment: Be careful when using a loop like this. You may want to check `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` to check that keys aren't being added by a prototype.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.