# Get key names from map of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I have a dynamic map of objects like this:

```
let specs = {source1:[{key1:value2, key2:value2, key3:value3}, {key1:value4, key2:value5, key3:value6}]
             source2:[{key4:value7, key5:value8, key6:value9}, {key4:value10, key5:value11, key6:value12}]
```

Key names (key1, key2 ...) vary.
I am looking for a way to extract key names for each source.
I want output like this:

```
source1_keys ={key1, key2, kye3}
source2_kyes = {key4, key5, key6}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get property names of objects in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911878/how-to-get-property-names-of-objects-in-array)

Comment: @HereticMonkey. It does. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` and get all the values of the first object in each array using `Object.keys`

**Note:** Below method will only get the keys of the first object inside each array.

```js
let specs = {source1:[{key1:'value2', key2:'value2', key3:'value3'}, {key1:'value4', key2:'value5', key3:'value6'}],
             source2:[{key4:'value7', key5:'value8', key6:'value9'}, {key4:'value10', key5:'value11', key6:'value12'}]};
             
const keys = Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(specs)
                   .map(([k, v]) => [k, Object.keys(v[0])])
             );
console.log(keys)
```

If you want to get all the unique keys from each element of the array then use the below method

```js
let specs = {source1:[{key1:'value2', key2:'value2', key3:'value3'}, {key1:'value4', extra1:'value5', key3:'value6'}],
             source2:[{key4:'value7', key5:'value8', key6:'value9'}, {key4:'value10', extra2:'value11', key6:'value12'}]};
             
const keys = Object.fromEntries(
                Object.entries(specs)
                   .map(([k, v]) => [k, [...new Set(v.flatMap(x => Object.keys(x)))]])
             );
console.log(keys)
```